# Should I jump directly to "differential geometry"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, learning

I am a (now) math major who has taken a standard undergraduate course in engineering multivariable calculus. I say "engineering" since the course was directed at engineers, and mainly focused on computation. Since then, I have actually taken real analysis too, covering chapters 1-9 of Rudin. It covers a little bit about multivariable calculus rigorously, but it doesn't really cover the vector calculus part. I have heard chapter 10 of Rudin is bad for this. Some suggestions I have gotten for it is "Calculus on Manifolds" by Spivak and "Analysis on Manifolds" by Munkres. However, since I have taken plenty of higher level math courses (including topology) and generally feel mathematically mature, perhaps I could take a course in differential geometry at this point instead? From what I have understood, it covers vector calculus and generalises it to smooth manifolds, provided you know the inverse/implicit function theorems, differentiation in multiple dimensions and the chain rule.

Am I correct, or would I do myself a disservice by skipping rigorous vector calculus? If so, what would I miss if I were to skip it?

Comment: If you're an engineer there's no need to do most of that.

Comment: I was initially going to be an engineering major, but I switched to math once I got really interested. That is why I took the engineering calculus course.

Comment: You realize that engineering is an interesting and well paid profession?

Comment: If you try to jump straight into diff. geometry, I suspect you would be in need of the vector calculus quickly: it is true that diff geometry generalizes vector calculus in some sense, however, it uses vector calculus to do this. Namely, you cannot do without implicit function theorem and theorem on local diffeomorphism. I suspect there will be no diff. geometry texts that cover these things, they just assume them.

Comment: @selfawareuser: Yes, I do. But I realized that it was not for me when I realized how much I like mathematics.

Comment: @PavelČoupek: I know about differentiation in Euclidean space, the chain rule, and inverse/implicit function theorems already, from Rudin. At least I understand the theorems, their conditions/exact statements and their proofs. Is there anything more about vector calculus that I need to do differential geometry?

Comment: It's probably best if you talk to the instructor of that differential geometry course.  He/she will know more than we do about what level of mathematical preparation the course assumes, and will also be better able to assess whether you have that level, or what you need to do to fill in any gaps.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I noticed now that I have taken all of its course prerequisites. Perhaps my question is more about if there is anything essential that I am missing by not taking vector analysis itself, that I simply won't learn in diff geo.

Comment: @SamJeanson I would not dare to say "no, you don't need anything more". : )) Although I suspect the above mentioned theorems are the two most needed. I think if you have some working knowledge then that should be probably OK. From the first courses of diff. geo. I remember also some easy optimization coming up (lagrange multipliers etc.), but I suspect you covered that in engineering calculus more than enough. It, is, of course, dependent on the contents of the course (if the goal is e.g. Stokes theorem, some (multivariate) integration skills are needed as well).

Comment: You can try skipping it for the moment, and then coming back to it (rigorous vector calculus) as and when needed.

Comment: @PavelČoupek: I learned the integration *skills* in the calculus course. Isn't integration formally covered in differential geometry too?

Comment: @SamJeanson Depends on the course, I guess. I would suspect that a differential geometry course would try to define integral of a function on a (compact, orientable) manifold using the definition of an integral of multivariate function in R^n, and not bother with defining that one. Also substitution theorem (in multivariate form) is neeeded all the time for doing this.